# Power Bi - Count for a category for each month

Tags: powerbi

I am just starting out with PowerBi. Please use the table below as my sample. Assume that the Order Table has a *-1 relationship with Order Status.

I want to create a bar graph to see the number of each Order Status by Month.

The month is at the bottom and each month potentially has 3 bars. 1 bar representing the count of each Order Status for that month.

I need some direction. I know this is an open-ended question, but I at a total loss.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the same tables as you provided and joined them on order status id (*-1 relationship). Then created the status column.

```
Status = RELATED('Order Status'[Status] )
```

Dragged and dropped this column on to the clustered column chart under legend and values (default summarised as count). Then got the following visual.
[image]

Comment: when you say 'Then created the status column.' do you mean you created a column in 'Order' table?

Comment: Yes. I created that calculated column (Status) in order table.